# How do I create a new Realm instance with the Realm Browser

Tags: swift, realm

I'm using the Realm browser to view the data I'm creating using realm.io + swift

but how do I create a new .realm file to use in my project?

Comment: When you start using it, like "[Realm defaultRealm]", it will create on for you if already not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, it is not possible to create new Realm files with the Browser.

Comment: Thank you. In the ['Migrations' example](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/swift/Migration) there are other realms used that get copied to the documents directory at run time. How do these get created?

Comment: Those get created in code (usually by the same application that will end up consuming them), and then moved into the app's bundle.